# My TextView.OnEditorActionListener() doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am creating an app for a conductor of a game. In this game, the conductor has to enter each and every players' names in an EditText box, the names will be saved in a String Array for future role assignments.

My EditText id is addplayer, and I have assigned a setOnEditorActionListener() method to it.

I have added this condition `if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)` in its body.

None of my commands work though.

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    static List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    static int playerSum = 0;

    RelativeLayout firstActLayout;
    TextView numberOfPlayers;
    EditText addPlayer;
    TextView doneButton;
    TextView settingsButton;
    InputMethodManager imm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_activity);

        firstActLayout = findViewById(R.id.first_act_layout);
        numberOfPlayers = findViewById(R.id.number_of_players);
        addPlayer = findViewById(R.id.add_player);
        doneButton = findViewById(R.id.done_button);
        settingsButton = findViewById(R.id.settings_button);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.add_player:
                addPlayers();
                break;
            case R.id.done_button:
                openSecondActivity();
                break;
            case R.id.settings_button:

                break;
        }
    }

    public void addPlayers (){
        addPlayer.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                    // add player's name to the name array.
                    names.add(addPlayer.getText().toString());
                    // increment the total number of players.
                    playerSum++;
                    // display the total number of players next the hash tag.
                    numberOfPlayers.append(Integer.toString(playerSum), 8, 12);
                    // keep the soft keyboard available for the next entry.
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

XML:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/add_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:autofillHints="@string/enter_name"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="@string/enter_name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#FF030303"
        tools:targetApi="o"
        />
```

I want the conductor to be able to:
1. enter the name in the EditText
2. and press the next icon on the soft Keyboard.

The public void addPlayers () should:
1. take the added name and assign it to the names [] array,
2. delete the EditText box for the next entry,
3. increment the number of players with playerSum++,
4. display the total number of players (playerSum++) in a TextView box (numberOfPlayers).
5. keep the soft keyboard on display for the next name.

but nothing happens. The name of the player sits in the EditText box.

Comment: Did you debug to check what action id are you getting in this line if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) ? and is control entering this if block or not?

Comment: Just debugged and got this message: E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
    SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

Comment: apparently that error message has something to do with the keyboard, I deleted all updates on my android keyboard and debugged again and didn't get that error message again, but my original problem hasn't been solved.

Comment: Okay I found a solution but I still don't know why it didn't work. I took out the EditText out of the switch- case and implemented the addplayer() in the onStart(). I had 2 additional bugs afterwards, one  when I tried to display the total number of players and another with the soft keyboard again. I managed to resolve both. The app works fine now but I would like to know why I can't use the EditText in the switch-case.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just realized where I went wrong. I had forgotten to add these 3 lines:

```
    addPlayer.setOnClickListener(this);
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    settingsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

When I think about it, this question was pretty stupid, lol. How would the buttons work without a setter method? duhhh.